# If I remove "package-enable-at-startup" line, what is the effect?

Tags: init-file

I have this line in my `early-init.el` file:

```
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
```

By removing this line I basically tell Emacs to

> make installed packages available before loading the init.el file.

Right? I'm asking this question because I'm confused about its purpose. Is my definition correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's correct. Or rather, by putting that line into early-init.el you had told Emacs to not activate your packages automatically (which is otherwise the default behaviour), so you're reverting back to that default by removing it.